# Problems with height of containers with Angular Material Tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

I'm making an Angular-app using Angular Material, and I'm having big issue with the height of my tab content. This is my first attempt at Angular, but I'm familiar with HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

The situation is that I have an app with the MatSidenav component, and inside the `Sidenav` content I have a `MatTab` component, which contains a wrapper to load other components dynamically into new tabs. This all works as I want it to, the problem is the content of the tabs, specifically the tabs that get their content after the tab is created (e.g. tabs containing components that load data from the REST service).

I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e7zcx7) based on my actual app, to illustrate the problem.

When going to "Test One" from the menu, it only shows the buttons on the top. The "Get Data" button will simply populate the `BehaviorSubject` that the data table (AgGrid) uses, (sort of an attempt at simulating a REST-call, which the actual app has). All gets populated and shown as I want, but the container element (one of them, I can't for the life of me figure out which one is the actual cuprit) isn't high enough, so the table doesn't actually show.
The "Test Two" is just an example of a tab with static content, which displays as I expected (same as the Home-tab really).

I've put a button to toggle the `height` property of the `container-div` of the table between 500px and blank. Of course, this would be great if I wanted a static height value of 500px (or any px value), but I want it to be as high as the remaining part of the viewport.

I've tried messing with the `dynamicHeight` property of the `mat-tab-group`, but if I turn that off it causes a whole deal of other problems since I have tabs with very variable content heights.
I've also tried with various flexbox settings, using both Bootstrap d-flex as well as Angulars own ngFlex, but nothing seems to work.

Now this specific case is for the `AgGrid` table, but I'm having the same issue with a tab with Google Maps embedded, but I figure if I can solve this one, I'll be able to apply a similar method to fix the maps issue. I'm assuming it is caused by the content changing after the page has been rendered, but that's sort of the point as well, and so that the CSS doesn't seem to keep up confuses the hell out of me.

The only way I've managed to solve this, is by using JavaScript and setting the heights of various elements in `ngAfterViewInit` and binding an event to window resize, but this seems like a very hack-ish way of doing it, and it also means I have to do it for all components that can be loaded into tabs, not just where I'm currently having problems (because I have to set the height of several of the Tab container elements, which will be the same elements even when tabs are switched).

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've only used ag-grid sparingly, but I have noticed that they handle height strangely. I think you're missing a 'autoHeight' domLayout property:

```
<ag-grid-angular
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
    class="ag-theme-balham mat-elevation-z8"
    [rowData]="loadedData"
    [columnDefs]="agtablecolumns"
    [domLayout]="'autoHeight'"
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Adding that in the stackblitz caused an empty table to appear before any data is retrieved, though. Not sure if that's the goal.

Comment: Thank you! That did work, although I used domLayout="autoHeight" as it's not necessary to use property binding for a static string value. In my actual app, the whole container div is hidden if there is no data to display, so that's exactly how it should work.
That does leave me with the Google Maps-problem, which doesn't have any such property as far as I know. Now, should I post a new case (and stackblitz) for that, or do I update this one? I'm apparently still learning the proper way of doing things on stackoverflow :)

Comment: I spoke too soon - although that did work, it is not quite what I'm trying to achieve. Using this method, the header row of the table will scroll up with the rest. It does work, but it doesn't let me have the table scroll down while having the header pinned to the top. If that's not possible, this solution is something I can live with, but it's not quite optimal.